# Trouble with Cursor Movement Using Ctrl + a and Ctrl + e in Asahi Linux KDE Plasma on MacBook Air M1

Tags: arch-linux, kde, desktop-environment, macintosh

I'm currently using Asahi Linux on my MacBook Air M1 and I've encountered an issue that I can't seem to resolve. In my environment, specifically in applications like Firefox, I'm unable to move my cursor to the beginning of the text using `Ctrl + a` or to the end of the text using `Ctrl + e`. Instead of moving the cursor, these commands are selecting all the text.

This behavior is only present in graphical applications and not in the terminal where the shortcuts are working as expected.

Here's the basic information about my environment:

```
OS: Asahi Linux(Arch)
Desktop: KDE Plasma 
Machine: MacBook Air M1 (aach64)
Affected Applications: Firefox (possibly others)
```

I checked the key bindings in the system settings, but unfortunately could not find where the settings could be changed correctly.

Has anyone else experienced this issue or have any insights into what might be causing this behavior? Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot or fix this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: this sounds like default behaviour! ctrl-a being "select all text" has a *really* long-standing history in graphical applications. I'm sadly not aware of a way of telling the diverse graphical toolkits that implement these edit boxes that they should consistently listen to other keys, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Why is this the hotkey behavior?

Standard default behavior for `Ctrl+a` is select all text in graphical applications and is determined by the application's default hot keys. Afaik, there is no default behavior for `Ctrl+e`.

When in graphical applications when editing text, I personally use `Ctrl+a` then left arrow key to go to beginning of text, and `Ctrl+a` right arrow key to go to the end of the text.

For example, Firefox's default hotkeys while editing text in a text box list `Ctrl+a` for "Select All": https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly#w_editing

They also list the following default hot keys for while editing text:

- `Ctrl+Home` to "Go to Beginning of Text"
- `Ctrl+End` to "Go to End of Text"
- `Home` to "Go to Beginning of Line"
- `End` to "Go to Beginning of Line"

These may be standard defaults across graphical applications. I do not know because I don't typically use them.

## How to change the hotkeys?

What if you want the exact behavior your want? Can this be done? Perhaps it is possible to change the individual application's hotkeys when editing text.

Notably, the linked Firefox page on "Keyboard shortcuts" states in the beginning paragraph:

> If you have enabled Emacs-style text editing shortcuts in GNOME, they will also work in Firefox.

I use vim, so I am not familiar with Emacs-style shortcuts, but perhaps there is something similar for KDE?

Notably, KDE's default document editing is same as Firefox: https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/khelpcenter/fundamentals/kbd.html#kbd-modifying

> The shortcuts described in Working with Documents and Getting Help are set by individual programs. **Most KDE programs allow you to use the common shortcut editing dialog to modify these.** The shortcuts described in Working With Files can be edited in the same manner ...
> emphasis mine.

KDE has docs on using and customizing shortcuts:
https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/khelpcenter/fundamentals/shortcuts.html

So worst case scenario, is you have to modify the hotkeys for every individual application to get the behavior you want.

Notably state in those docs, if you have a friend using your machine and they are unfamiliar with your hotkeys, you can set up "Schemes" that seem to serve as profiles for different hotkey behavior.

To open the KDE shortcuts config panel: `Settings` -> `Configure Shortcuts...`

There are "Standard Shortcuts" under system settings, shortcuts in KDE (different from Global Shortcuts) and it appears you can edit them, so that would avoid having to apply them to every application individually. This is stated in this blog post (I am *not* the author, I don't have KDE available to me to test this): https://www.maketecheasier.com/assign-remap-keyboard-shortcuts-in-linux/

These KDE docs discuss Standard shortcuts and Global Shortcuts here: https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/plasma-desktop/kcontrol/keys/index.html#key-bindings-use-globapp

They note that they may not apply to all applications if the application overrides them, meaning you may have to specify it individually for such applications.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately there is no "Standard Shortcuts" section under system settings on on KDE (probably my Asashi settings) but I could capture how KDE settings work so I appreciate a lot.